# Sonata Batch Operations & Hooks Doctrine

Tags: php, curl, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

i've created an admin panel with Sonata (Symfony2 Bundle http://sonata-project.org/about) and i've added an event in the preRemove hook (Doctrine).

In few words when i delete a record,  run a curl to an other service.
Everythings works.

**But** Sonata have also the "Batch Operations" where i can select multiple lines and choose "Delete all selected".

**But**, if i choose "delete all selected" the curl not started.
The preRemove hook (Doctrine) it's not called.

There is someone that can help me?!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, that batch delete action really avoids calling `preRemove` method (see `Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController::batchActionDelete` which calls `Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Model\ModelManager::batchDelete`).

However, you have options:

1. Override that `batchActionDelete` by using custom controller extending `CRUDController`.  [SonataMediaBundle does that](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/blob/feae2c3eb60c41b4a1b51315c0ff2f35e567329c/Admin/Manager/DoctrineORMManager.php).
2. Register real doctrine event (not recommended) ([Symfony cookbook tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html))

Comment: Thanks. I've extended the Sonata CRUD Controller and i've created a new action. ;)

Answer (score 2):

There is another option, you can use the preBatchAction hook in your admin class.

```
public function preBatchAction($actionName, ProxyQueryInterface $query, array & $idx, $allElements)
{
    if ($actionName == 'delete') {
         // logic here
    }
}
```

See https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/batch_actions.html#optional-executing-a-pre-batch-hook